# ListView Databinding with custom views

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, data-binding

I'm trying to get a custom list of custom views (I eventually will add controls to each view) displayed using databinding in a xamarin project. However when I run my project, nothing shows up on the list. I'm kind of new to the databinding stuff so I'm a little confused. I've searched and tried some other solutions but haven't been able to figure out my specific issue. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinTuts.XMainPage">

  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Tasks:" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" x:Name="tasksLabel"></Label>
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding taskItems}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="5">
              <Grid>
                <StackLayout Name="TextStack" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0">
                  <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                  <Label Text="{Binding Description}"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Name="ButtonStack" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End" Grid.Column="1">
                  <Button Name="Edit" Text="Edit" Width="50" Height="50"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
              </Grid>
            </Frame>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>

    </StackLayout>

  </ContentPage.Content>  

</ContentPage>
```

That's my XAML. Here's my XMainPage.cs:

```
public partial class XMainPage : ContentPage
{


    TestViewModel vm;

    public XMainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        vm = new TestViewModel();

        TaskListItem testItem = new TaskListItem(this, "Go shopping", "Drive to meijer and get the following: Milk, Eggs, Booze");
        TaskListItem testItem2 = new TaskListItem(this, "Play Overwatch", "Pwn some n00bs");
        vm.taskItems.Add(testItem);
        vm.taskItems.Add(testItem2);


        BindingContext = vm;
    }

}
```

Followed by my TestViewModel.cs:

```
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    ObservableCollection<TaskListItem> mtaskItems;

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        mtaskItems = new ObservableCollection<TaskListItem>();
    }


    public ObservableCollection<TaskListItem> taskItems
    {
        get
        {
            return mtaskItems;
        }
        set
        {
            mtaskItems = value;
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string name = null)
    {

        var changed = PropertyChanged;

        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    }
}
```

Followed by my TaskListItem.cs:

```
public class TaskListItem : ViewCell
{

    public Task newTask;

    String mName;
    String mDescription;

    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return mName;
        }
    }

    public String Description
    {
        get
        {
            return mDescription;
        }
    }


    public TaskListItem(ContentPage taskListItemParent, String TaskName, String TaskDescription)
    {
        //newTask = new Task(TaskName, TaskDescription);

        mName = TaskName;
        mDescription = TaskDescription;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set the BindingContext property on on the view. You should Create a ViewModel and have the Observable Collection as a public property.

```
    TestViewModel vm;

    public XMainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vm = new TestViewModel();

        BindingContext = vm;
    }
```

When using Xamarin.Forms it is recommended to follow the MVVM Pattern. [Here is a simple sample](https://github.com/xamarin/dev-days-labs/tree/master/HandsOnLab/Finish) project written that your help you understand better data binding and how all the pieces connect together. Also, in [this chapter of the Xamarin.Forms book](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter16/) DataBinding is explained very well

Comment: I've updated my code with your suggestion and it's still not working for me. It looks like I have it set up correctly but nothing is showing up on the page. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Turns out I had some invalid XAML. After fiddling with it a bit I was able to get it to correctly display. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It sucks that those errors can't be found at compile time. I'm glad the information was of help